# How to span lookup relationship in django?

Tags: django

Where am i goofing in the following lookup?

My models:

```
Class Item(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ....

Class Stock(models.Model):
    item_code = models.ForeignKey( Item )
    qty       = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Now i want to get all Stock objects with Item.item_code

```
stock_items = Stock.objects.filter(item__item_code__contains='101')
```

I get the error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'item' into field. Choices are: id, item_code, qty, restock_level, userid
```

What am i missing?

Gath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use following:

```
stock_items = Stock.objects.filter(item_code__item_code__contains='101')
```

First field name is field in Stock model, in this case item_code, not item.

In order to use in way you did. You would have to change your Stock model to following:

```
Class Stock(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
```

Then this would work:

```
stock_items = Stock.objects.filter(item__item_code__contains='101')
```

Comment: Thanks, its confusing especially if you follow the Django documentation on this; http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/